# Finding a (small) prime great enough that there are at least m elements of order m

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, prime-numbers, finite-groups

I'm hoping that someone can provide me with some results or point me in the right direction.

I'm working with finite fields; really, I'm just doing arithmetic modulo a prime $p$.  I'm taking elements to powers, so I believe this deals with the multiplicative group in particular.  Now I basically require that there are at least $m$ elements of a certain order (or greater).  We can call this order $n$.  I'm wondering if there's a fairly simple and/or easy way to get an estimate of $p$, like how great $p$ must be.  The idea is, I want to work with a prime that's big enough to contain $m$ elements of order $n$, but preferably not much larger than the minimum prime that does so.

**Extra Credit**
I'd like an easy way to find the $m$ elements of order $n$.  I'm really looking for the simplest way to accomplish both of these goals.

***MAIN GOAL***
I'm trying to ensure that $p$ doesn't need to be astronomically large compared to $m$ and $n$.

Comment: At the risk of asking the obvious, do you mean order in the multiplicative group?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, assuming $n$ is a divisor of $p-1$, then the Euler's totient function $\phi(n)$ gives you the number of elements of order $n$.

Comment: @John M:  I'm taking numbers to powers.  So for example, I'd say the order of 2 modulo 7 is 3 since $2^0\equiv1$ and $2^3\equiv1$.  I think that this is the multiplicative group.

Comment: NOTE:  I don't need to be very precise here.  This is to attempt to speed up an algorithm, so I may end up going through every number between 1 and $p$ and finding its order.  As long as $p$ isn't astronomically large compared to $m$ and $n$, things should suffice.  Also, $m$ and $n$ are probably close in value.

Comment: Continuing the example of $\pmod 7, \phi(6)=2$, so there are two elements of order $6$, namely $3$ and $5$.  As remarked below, there are a fair number of elements of maximum order, so just trying until you find one will be reasonable.  Once you have found one, taking it to powers coprime to $p-1$ will get you the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a specific estimate for $p$:
Pick prime $p \geq \max(n+1,m^2+1,11) $.  Then you'll have $\phi(p-1)$ elements of order $p-1$ which is greater than or equal to desired order $n$.
Noting that we have the lower bound $\phi(n) \geq \sqrt n$ for $n > 6$, you'll have $\phi(p-1) \geq m$.

Answer (score 4):

The following should give you a start. Any prime $p$ has $\phi(p-1)$ primitive roots, where $\phi$ is the Euler $\phi$-function.

In the literature, you can find explicit lower bounds for $\phi(n)$ in terms of $n$.  It turns out that $\phi(n)$ cannot be much smaller than $n$. If memory serves right (and it often doesn't) we can't get much below $n/(\ln n)$ if $n$ is at all large.

If, as in your case, we are satisfied with elements of large but not necessarily maximum order, we can proceed as follows.

Let $g$ be a primitive root of $p$, and let $d$ be a positive divisor of $\phi(p)$.  Then $g^k$ has order $d$ modulo $p$ if and only if $k$ is of the form $j\phi(p)/d$, where $\gcd(j,d)=1$.  Thus there are exactly $\phi(d)$ incongruent elements of order $d$ modulo $p$.

So by taking $d=(p-1)/2$, we get another big collection of elements of large order.

Being largely ignorant in computational number theory, I must decline the opportunity for extra credit.

**Added**: If $\phi(p)$ happens to be on the small side compared to $p$, that's because $p-1$ has too many small divisors $d$.  But then there is some compensation because of the elements of large order $(p-1)/d$.

Comment: Note that the order $d$ must divide $\phi(p)=p-1$, so OP will need a prime such that $p\equiv 1 \pmod{d}$.

Comment: According to how I read the original problem, $m=d$ and $n=\phi(d)$ are givens, and a prime $p$ is an unknown that is sought after. So you can't "start with $p$," can you?

Comment: Oh, you're right. I skimmed too hastily.

Answer (score 2):

The multiplicative group is cyclic of order $p-1$, so there are $\phi(p-1)$ elements of order $p-1$, where $\phi$ is [Euler's totient function.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)  You can also calculate how many are of each lesser order if you know the factorization of $p-1$.  There is a small discussion of this in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group) and more details in any group theory book.  So $p$ doesn't have to be much greater than $m$.