# Can we always solve these linear algebra equations given rows of multiples?

Tags: matrices, ring-theory

We can find $n$ elements of multiplicative order $(n+1)$ modulo some large prime $p$, according to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52078/finding-a-small-prime-great-enough-that-there-are-at-least-m-elements-of-order).  Now I'm wondering if we can always perform linear algebra on the elements, as follows.

We take the $k$th element, call it $a_k$.  Then we form a row as follows:
$$(a_k)^1, (a_k)^2, (a_k)^3, \dots, (a_k)^n$$

So essentially we have a matrix that looks like:

$$(a_1)^1, (a_1)^2, (a_1)^3, \dots, (a_1)^n$$
$$(a_2)^1, (a_2)^2, (a_2)^3, \dots, (a_2)^n$$
$$(a_3)^1, (a_3)^2, (a_3)^3, \dots, (a_3)^n$$
$$\dots$$
$$(a_n)^1, (a_n)^2, (a_n)^3, \dots, (a_n)^n$$

Let's say we calculate all entries of the matrix modulo $p$.  Can someone prove or disprove that we can always reduce the matrix into reduced row echelon form?

Comment: Up to a reordering of columns, it is a Vandermonde matrix. I think that means yes.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews This one has ${a_i}^n$ as the last column. All $a_i$, if I haven't misunderstood, are supposed to have order $n$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Oops, I didn't mean to repeat values.  I'll correct the question.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah, missed that.

Comment: Even if we only demand that the order of each $a_i$ is at least $n$ (or at least $n+1$, or anything greater), it's still $D\cdot V$ with $D$ an invertible diagonal matrix, and $V$ a Vandermonde matrix.

Comment: It's actually of that form even if the $a_i$ are of order $<n$, too. :) Nothing about Vandermond requires any property on the order. @DanielFischer