# Can we find a reduced row-echelon form for these matrices?

Tags: matrices, intuition, block-matrices

Starting with a [Vandermonde matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix):

$$V =
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1^1 & 1^2 & 1^3 & \dots & 1^n \\
        2^1 & 2^2 & 2^3 & \dots & 2^n \\
        3^1 & 3^2 & 3^3 & \dots & 3^n \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        n^1 & n^2 & n^3 & \dots & n^n \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

...which, [according to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433860/can-we-always-solve-these-linear-algebra-equations-given-rows-of-multiples), always has a solution in reduced row-echelon form, we can extend the matrix to include additional columns:

$$V(a) =
        \begin{bmatrix}
        (a_0)^1 & (a_0)^2 & (a_0)^3 & \dots & (a_0)^n \\
        (a_1)^1 & (a_1)^2 & (a_1)^3 & \dots & (a_1)^n \\
        (a_2)^1 & (a_2)^2 & (a_2)^3 & \dots & (a_2)^n \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        (a_n)^1 & (a_n)^2 & (a_n)^3 & \dots & (a_n)^n \\
        (a_{n+1})^1 & (a_{n+1})^2 & (a_{n+1})^3 & \dots & (a_{n+1})^n \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        (a_m)^1 & (a_m)^2 & (a_m)^3 & \dots & (a_m)^n
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

The idea is that we can add two extended matrices together, like so:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} V(a) \, | \, 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$B=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \, | \, V(b) \end{bmatrix}$$
$$A+B = \begin{bmatrix} V(a) \, | \, V(b) \end{bmatrix}$$

...We should be able to reduce this to the identity.  My question is, what if the columns overlap?  In other words, if we have:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} V(a) \, | \, V(a_2) \, | \, 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$B=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \, | \, V(b) \, | \, V(b_2) \end{bmatrix}$$
$$A+B = \begin{bmatrix} V(a) \, | \, V(a_2) + V(b) \, | \, V(b_2) \end{bmatrix}$$

I believe that this should still reduce to the identity.  Am I correct?  Could someone possibly prove this?  Or, if a proof is elusive, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I should point out that the $a$ and $a_2$ in the final set of equations are just meant to be placeholders.  They're not necessarily related.